# What are the workaround options for python out of memory error?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, out-of-memory

I am reading a x,y,z point file (LAS) into python and have run into memory errors.  I am interpolating unknown points between known points for a project I am working on.  I began working with small files (< 5,000,000 points) and was able to read/write to a numpy array and python lists with no problem.  I have received more data to work with (> 50,000,000 points) and now my code fails with a MemoryError.

What are some options for handling such large amounts of data?  I do not have to load all data into memory at once, but I will need to look at neighboring points using [scipy kd-tree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) I am using Python 2.7 32 bit on a 64 bit Windows XP OS.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Code is posted below.  I took out code for long calculations and variable definitions.

```
from liblas import file
import numpy as np

f = file.File(las_file, mode='r')
num_points = int(f.__len__())
dt = [('x', 'f4'), ('y', 'f4'), ('z', 'f4'), ('i', 'u2'), ('c', 'u1'), ('t', 'datetime64[us]')]
xyzict = np.empty(shape=(num_points,), dtype = dt)
counter = 0
for p in f:
    newrow = (p.x, p.y, p.z, p.intensity, p.classification, p.time)
    xyzict[counter] = newrow    
    counter += 1

dropoutList = []
counter = 0
for i in np.nditer(xyzict):
    # code to define P1x, P1y, P1z, P1t
    if counter != 0:
        # code to calculate n, tDiff, and seconds 
        if n > 1 and n < scanN:
            # code to find v and vD
            for d in range(1, int(n-1)):
                # Code to interpolate x, y, z for points between P0 and P1
                # Append tuple of x, y, and z to dropoutList
                dropoutList.append(vD)
    # code to set x, y, z, t for next iteration
    counter += 1
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is giving the error? (Or a small snippet that reproduces the problem?) There may be a way to make it more efficient, but it's impossible to tell without the code.

Comment: Are you using `np.loadtxt` or `np.genfromtxt`?  If so, they're quite inefficient for large files. (Not to plug my own answer, but it's relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8964779/325565 ) You can either roll your own reader and use `fromiter` or, these days, just use pandas.  (Pandas happens to have a very efficient whitespace-delimited ascii reader.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regardless of the amount of RAM in your system, if you are running 32-bit python, you will have a practical limit of about 2 GB of RAM for your application. There are a number of other questions on SO that address this (e.g., see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282867/python-32-bit-memory-limits-on-64bit-windows)). Since the structure you are using in your ndarray is 23 bytes and you are reading over 50,000,000 points, that already puts you at about 1 GB. You haven't included the rest of your code so it isn't clear how much additional memory is being consumed by other parts of your program.

If you have well over 2 GB of RAM in your system and you will continue to work on large data sets, you should install 64-bit python to get around this ~ 2 GB limit.

Answer (score 2):

Save the points in a binary file on disk and then use [numpy.memmap](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) That'll be a bit slower but might not hurt (depending on the algorithm).

Or try the 64 bit version of Python; you probably need more than 2GB of data.

Lastly, check your code how it works with the data. With that many elements, you shouldn't try to copy / clone the array. Use views instead.

If everything else fails, try a 64bit version of Linux (since you won't get a 64bit Windows for free).

Comment: How is switching to Linux supposed to help with a Python out-of-memory error?  The dig on Windows here is completely gratuitous.

Comment: I'm not familiar with reading/writing binary files to disk (I'm a newb with python).

Comment: I think that part of the documentation refers to `numpy.save()`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.io.html

Comment: It sounds like the linux part is for cost concerns.