# Out of memory error in opening nifti file happens randomly

Tags: python, out-of-memory, nifti, nibabel

I'm trying to open a zipped nifty file using nibabel library (as nib) and the following code:

```
img = nib.load (nifti_file)
img_data = img.get_data ()
```

where `nifti_file` is a variable with the path to the file in the same directory.

On the second line, there is an out-of-memory error that happens 60% of the time randomly while I try running those two lines.
I have enough memory space on my computer so I'm not sure why this happens and also as I mentioned sometimes it simply works.

Comment: Make sure you are running the 64-bit version of Python. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1405971/277267

Comment: Hi, there is a discussion about similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960166/what-are-the-workaround-options-for-python-out-of-memory-error . I don't think you can do much but catching the exception, free memory and try again as described at https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#MemoryError .