# Gradient accumulation in an RNN

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, gradient-descent

I ran into some memory issues (GPU) when running a large RNN network, but I want to keep my batch size reasonable so I wanted to try out gradient accumulation. In a network where you predict the output in one go, that seems self-evident but in an RNN you do multiple forward passes for each input step. Because of that, I fear that my implementation does not work as intended. I started from user albanD's excellent examples [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-do-we-need-to-set-the-gradients-manually-to-zero-in-pytorch/4903/20) , but I think they should be modified when using an RNN. The reason I think that is because you accumulate much more gradients because you do multiple forwards per sequence.

My current implementation looks like this, at the same time allowing for AMP in PyTorch 1.6 which seems important - everything needs to be called in the right place. Note that this is just an abstract version, which might seem like a lot of code but it is mostly comments.

```py
def train(epochs):
    """Main training loop. Loops for `epoch` number of epochs. Calls `process`."""
    for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
        train_loss = process("train")
        valid_loss = process("valid")
        # ... check whether we improved over earlier epochs
        if lr_scheduler:
            lr_scheduler.step(valid_loss)
        
def process(do):
    """Do a single epoch run through the dataloader of the training or validation set. 
       Also takes care of optimizing the model after every `gradient_accumulation_steps` steps.
       Calls `step` for each batch where it gets the loss from."""
    if do == "train":
        model.train()
        torch.set_grad_enabled(True)
    else:
        model.eval()
        torch.set_grad_enabled(False)
    
    loss = 0.
    for batch_idx, batch in enumerate(dataloaders[do]):
        step_loss, avg_step_loss = step(batch)
        loss += avg_step_loss

        if do == "train":
            if amp:
                scaler.scale(step_loss).backward()

                if (batch_idx + 1) % gradient_accumulation_steps == 0:
                    # Unscales the gradients of optimizer's assigned params in-place
                    scaler.unscale_(optimizer)
                    # clip in-place
                    clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 2.0)
                    scaler.step(optimizer)
                    scaler.update()
                    model.zero_grad()
            else:
                step_loss.backward()
                if (batch_idx + 1) % gradient_accumulation_steps == 0:
                    clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 2.0)
                    optimizer.step()
                    model.zero_grad()
        
        # return average loss
        return loss / len(dataloaders[do])

    def step():
        """Processes one step (one batch) by forwarding multiple times to get a final prediction for a given sequence."""
        # do stuff... init hidden state and first input etc.
        loss = torch.tensor([0.]).to(device)
        
        for i in range(target_len):
            with torch.cuda.amp.autocast(enabled=amp):
                # overwrite previous decoder_hidden
                output, decoder_hidden = model(decoder_input, decoder_hidden)

                # compute loss between predicted classes (bs x classes) and correct classes for _this word_
                item_loss = criterion(output, target_tensor[i])

                # We calculate the gradients for the average step so that when
                # we do take an optimizer.step, it takes into account the mean step_loss
                # across batches. So basically (A+B+C)/3 = A/3 + B/3 + C/3
                loss += (item_loss / gradient_accumulation_steps)

            topv, topi = output.topk(1)
            decoder_input = topi.detach()
        
        return loss, loss.item() / target_len
```

The above does not seem to work as I had hoped, i.e. it still runs into out-of-memory issues very quickly. I think the reason is that `step` already accumulates so much information, but I am not sure.

Comment: First there are several [limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960166/what-are-the-workaround-options-for-python-out-of-memory-error) for the RAM. Second you can use [fil](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/crash-out-of-memory/#:~:text=Using%20Fil%20to%20debug%20out-of-memory%20crashes) to debug out-of-memory crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, I will only take care of `amp` enabled gradient accumulation, without amp the idea is the same. And your step presented runs under `amp` so let's stick to that.

### `step`

In [PyTorch documentation about amp](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/amp_examples.html#gradient-accumulation) you have an example of gradient accumulation. You should do it inside `step`. Each time you run `loss.backward()` gradient is accumulated inside tensor leafs which can be optimized by `optimizer`. Hence, your `step` should look like this (see comments):

```
def step():
    """Processes one step (one batch) by forwarding multiple times to get a final prediction for a given sequence."""
    # You should not accumulate loss on `GPU`, RAM and CPU is better for that
    # Use GPU only for calculations, not for gathering metrics etc.
    loss = 0

    for i in range(target_len):
        with torch.cuda.amp.autocast(enabled=amp):
            # where decoder_input is from?
            # I assume there is one in real code
            output, decoder_hidden = model(decoder_input, decoder_hidden)
            # Here you divide by accumulation steps
            item_loss = criterion(output, target_tensor[i]) / (
                gradient_accumulation_steps * target_len
            )


        scaler.scale(item_loss).backward()
        loss += item_loss.detach().item()

        # Not sure what was topv for here
        _, topi = output.topk(1)
        decoder_input = topi.detach()

    # No need to return loss now as we did backward above
    return loss / target_len
```

As you `detach` `decoder_input` anyway (so it is like totally new hidden input without history and parameters will be optimized based on that, **not based on all runs**) there is no need for `backward` in process. Also, you probably don't need `decoder_hidden`, if it isn't passed to the network, `torch.tensor` filled with zeros is passed implicitly.

Also we should divide by `gradient_accumulation_steps * target_len` as that's how many `backward`s we will run before single optimization step.

As some of your variables are ill-defined I assume you just made a scheme of what's going on.

Also, if you want the history to be kept you shouldn't `detach` `decoder_input`, in this case it would look like this:

```
def step():
    """Processes one step (one batch) by forwarding multiple times to get a final prediction for a given sequence."""
    loss = 0

    for i in range(target_len):
        with torch.cuda.amp.autocast(enabled=amp):
            output, decoder_hidden = model(decoder_input, decoder_hidden)
            item_loss = criterion(output, target_tensor[i]) / (
                gradient_accumulation_steps * target_len
            )

        _, topi = output.topk(1)
        decoder_input = topi

        loss += item_loss
    scaler.scale(loss).backward()
    return loss.detach().cpu() / target_len
```

This effectively goes through RNN multiple times and will probably raise OOM, not sure what you are after here. If that's the case there's not much you can do AFAIK as the RNN computations are simply too long to fit into the GPU.

### `process`

Only relevant part of this code is presented, so it would be:

```
loss = 0.0
for batch_idx, batch in enumerate(dataloaders[do]):
    # Here everything is detached from graph so we're safe
    avg_step_loss = step(batch)
    loss += avg_step_loss

    if do == "train":
        if (batch_idx + 1) % gradient_accumulation_steps == 0:
            # You can use unscale as in the example in PyTorch's docs
            # just like you did
            scaler.unscale_(optimizer)
            # clip in-place
            clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 2.0)
            scaler.step(optimizer)
            scaler.update()
            # IMO in this case optimizer.zero_grad is more readable
            # but it's a nitpicking
            optimizer.zero_grad()

# return average loss
return loss / len(dataloaders[do])
```

### Question-like

> [...] in an RNN you do multiple forward passes for each input step.
> Because of that, I fear that my implementation does not work as
> intended.

It does not matter. For each forward you should usually do one backward (seems to be the case here, see steps for possible options). After that we (usually) **don't need loss connected to graph** as we already performed `backpropagation`, got our gradients and are ready to optimize parameters.

> That loss needs to have history, as it goes back to the process loop
> where backward will be called on it.

No need to call `backward` in process as presented.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to me that you accumulate over time at different points: in `step` we accumulate in the `for i in range(target_len)` loop, and further we accumulate in the dataloader loop in `process` until `if (batch_idx + 1) % gradient_accumulation_steps == 0`. Shouldn't we then normalize the loss further?

`item_loss = criterion(output, target_tensor[i]) / (gradient_accumulation_steps * target_len)`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, `item_loss` should be normalized by `target_len` and `gradient_accumulation_steps` as that's the total of `backward`s called before optimizing.

Comment: Can you change that in your answer please?