# RAM issues with Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm running Python 2.7 with Pandas, everything installed
with Anacondas Win 32bit distribution.
I got 4GB RAM, around 3GB are effectively used by WinXP on my machine.
Whenever I'm running scripts and the free accessable RAM drops below
1 GB there is a memory error thrown by the Python console.
No windows errors are observed.
Are there any known issues related to WIndows 32 Bit, WInXP and the use of Python?

Comment: only 2GB are addressable in 32-bit space; python needs contiguous spaces so effectively you may yield much less. Use 64-bit.

Comment: To my knowledge 4 GB are addressable, effectively it's 3,1 GB. One process can use up to 2 GB. When the memory error is thrown, Python is still far below to GB, according to the windows task manager. Maybe the no contigous space causes the error, or something else I don't know.

Comment: 2gb is essentially the limit on 33-bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282867/python-32-bit-memory-limits-on-64bit-windows

Comment: When the memory error occurs, there is 130MB used by pythonw.exe and 678MB used by python.exe. So both processes are far below 2 GB.

Comment: that may be, but you may be doing something that requires a contiguous space.