# Numpy Read as Array fails when using float 32

Tags: python, numpy, gdal

I'm using python and gdal to do some image processing for Landsat satellite imagery
Essentially, I'm trying to convert the iamges to Tasseled Cap, but generally I am reading 7 arrays of int 16 that are 7281 x 8051 size renamed bands 1-5 and band 7, and fmask. fmask is a mask band of 0's and 1's.

```
 brightBand=( .2043*band1 + .4158*band2 + .5524*band3+.5741*band4+.3124*band5+ .2303*band7)*fmask
 greenBand=( -0.1603*band1+ -.2819*band2 + -.4934*band3 + .7940*band4 + -.0002*band5 + -.1446*band7)*fmask
 wetBand=( .0315*band1 + .2021*band2 + .3102*band3 + .1594*band4 + -.6806*band5 + -.6109*band7)*fmask
```

i can import the bands as int 16, not as float 32, but as soon as I try to do the operation above i receive a ***"Memory Error"*** message. I am using Spyder/Python 2.7 and the right python bindings. I have 64 GB of ram, but con only seem to use up to 2 or 8. I'm also using 32 bit python and gdal. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using a 32-bit version of Python and related utilities? There shouldn't be anything stopping you from using 64-bit versions.

Comment: There is no reason to do your operation all at once since it is 'pixelwise'. So if you are limited on ram, do it block-by-block and write the results to disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How would you address more than 4gb with 32bit process? In fact, usually you are limited with 2Gb. It might be configured to be more on [unix machines](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/658638), but on windows, 32bit processes are [always limited with 2Gb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282867/python-32-bit-memory-limits-on-64bit-windows).

Switch to 64bit python instead.

Comment: Thank you all for confirming my suspicions. Any good ideas for 64 bit python similar to python xy and spyder?