# how to merge multiple dataframes inside one file, python

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

In my code i have received result like this one:

```
A B C
1 1 1
A B C
2 2 2
A B C
3 3 3
```

I need to merge those columns (dataframes) to one big dataframe
like

```
 A B C
 1 1 1
 2 2 2
 3 3 3
```

To merge dataframes from different files its ease like `pd.merge(df1,df2)` but how to do it when dataframes are in one file?
Thanks in advice!

EDIT: 
to receive my data i converted the lines in my dataset to get dataframes, and i have received in one output each dataset for each line.
my code:

```
def coordinates():
    with open('file.txt') as file:
        for lines in file:
            lines =StringIO(lines[35:61]) #i need only those fields in each line
            abc=pd.read_csv(lines,sep=' ',header=None)
            abc.columns=['A', 'B', 'C','D','E','F']
            print abc

coordinates()
```

EDIT2:
Proposition from s_vishnu its only good for prapared file with same multiple headers. But in my case i have multiple DataFrames generated to the file and each line after header have 0 value. It's many dataframes and each have only one line.

EDIT3:
in my `file.txt` i have big amount of lines with about 80 letters in line like this:

`AAA S S SSDAS ASDJAI A 234 33 43 234 2342999 2.31 22 33
 SSS S D W2UUQ Q231WQ A 222 11 23 123 1231299 2.31 22 11`

and from those line i need only part of information so thats why i did `lines =StringIO(lines[35:61])` to take this info. In this example i will need letters 
`[30:55]` and create dataframe with them with`columns=['A', 'B', 'C','D','E','F'] with sep=' '`

Comment: Maybe the answer to this one will help you 
 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715393/how-to-concatenate-multiple-pandas-dataframes-without-running-into-memoryerror

Answer (score 0):

`my_test.csv`:

```
A, B, C
1, 1 ,1
A, B, C
2, 2, 2
A, B, C
3, 3, 3
```

Use **list slicing**.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("my_test.csv")
df=df[::2]
print(df)
```

output:

```
   A    B   C
0  1   1    1
2  2    2   2
4  3    3   3
```

**df=df[::2]** This is advanced list slicing. Where in `df[::2]` the 2 means starting from 0 increment by 2 step.

But **note** the index values. They too are in steps of 2. i.e `0,2,4,..` to change the index just do this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("my_test.csv")
df=df[::2]

df.index = range(len(df['A']))
print(df)
```

output:

```
   A    B   C
0  1   1    1
1  2    2   2
2  3    3   3
```

So you get the values you desire.

Comment: hello . My output its still same, its doesnt work in my case with my code. i am receiving still:
    `   A  B  C
    0 1  1   1
       A  B  C
    0 2   2   2` and etc..

Comment: `In my code i have received result like this one` this is what you specified right? How did you get this? Apply my code after once you get what you mentioned it will work

Comment: please take a look on my code in my question. Its not a one frame with multiple headers, its multiple dataframes and each dataframe have one same header, maybe thats why it doesn't work on my dataset?

Comment: Okay man will look. Just can you post what's in your `file.txt`

Comment: ,i have edit my question, i think i can do my code better at the beggining where i am taking letters from the lines, and if someone could help me to create only one dataframe and if that will be possible i will not need to merge those dataframes which i have right now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, I've changed the code at the beginning and that was helpfull:

```
def coordinates():
abc=open('file.txt')
lines=abc.readlines()
        for line in lines:
        abc2=line[20:-7] #i just cut the lines from the begining and from the end, and i dont need to take data from the middle
        abc3=abc2.split()
        pd.DataFrame(abc3) 
        print abc3

coordinates()
```