# Append multidimensional numpy array to existing pandas dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am trying to append a numpy array into an already existing dataframe.

```
df_train = pd.DataFrame()
sk_train = sklearn_representation_train.toarray()
```

The shape of both dataframe and sk_train is:

```
sk_train
-> array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ..., 
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

sk_train.shape
-> (95851, 2000)

df_train.shape
-> (95851, 9)
```

How do convert the sk_train numpy array to dataframe and concatenate it to df_train?

Comment: Have you looked at `DataFrame.append` or `DataFrame.concat` depending on how you want things to line up?

Comment: `x = np.zeros((100,200));
y = np.zeros((100, 90));
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x),pd.DataFrame(y)])`

Comment: @skrubber I am facing memory error while performing this operation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715393/how-to-concatenate-multiple-pandas-dataframes-without-running-into-memoryerror