# Is there any way to use more than 2GB of memory in 32 bit python application in 64bit windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, memory, 32bit-64bit

Currently I'm developing some python application using 32 bit OCX file. Since it is 32 bit OCX file, I'm forced to use 32 bit python application.

I found that 32 bit application on windows can have maximum 2GB of memory. However, I want to use more memory because I have 16GB of memory available in my computer and my application's performance goes up as I use more memory.

Is there any way to use more than 2GB of memory in 32 bit python application in 64 bit windows? (Probably rebuilding python?? but unfortunately I don't know how to rebuild it..) ( It's Python 3)

Comment: The multiprocessing module :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 32-bit memory limits on 64bit windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282867/python-32-bit-memory-limits-on-64bit-windows)