# Handling two large dataframes - issue when using np.isin

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Example:

```
row=['12347','Van','18/01/2017']
npvalues = np.array([ ['12345','Bus','23/02/2017'],['12346','Truck','01/07/2017'],['12347','Van','18/01/2017']  ])
np.isin(row, npvalues)
```

Required output: `[True, True, True]`

> ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.

Comment: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool) .... np.version.version 1.13.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the 'row' variable to an np.array instead of a list.

```
import numpy as np
row=['12347','Van','18/01/2017']
npvalues = np.array([ ['12345','Bus','23/02/2017'],['12346','Truck','01/07/2017'],['12347','Van','18/01/2017']  ])

row
Out[60]: ['12347', 'Van', '18/01/2017']

npvalues
Out[61]: 
array([['12345', 'Bus', '23/02/2017'],
       ['12346', 'Truck', '01/07/2017'],
       ['12347', 'Van', '18/01/2017']],
      dtype='<U10')

# Cast instead
row = np.asarray(row)
np.isin(row, npvalues)
Out[63]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

**Note** - I was able to run your code as is, and get the answer required.

```
row=['12347','Van','18/01/2017']
npvalues = np.array([ ['12345','Bus','23/02/2017'],['12346','Truck','01/07/2017'],['12347','Van','18/01/2017']  ])
np.isin(row, npvalues)
Out[64]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Here are my version infos

```
import sys
sys.version
Out[71]: '3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 12 2018, 20:20:50) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'
np.version.full_version
Out[67]: '1.13.3'
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

My code is working fine when using in a small dataframe.

It will raise error if count is larger than 5000

Comment: When which array has > 5000 elements? Unfortunately as you are using 32bit you will hit memory restrictions earlier. What RAM have you got available for the process?

Comment: npvalues > 5000. I'm using 8GB Ram

Comment: Do you have a 64 bit processor? If so, I would strongly advise uninstalling your 32bit version of python and installing 64bit instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282867/python-32-bit-memory-limits-on-64bit-windows - You will increase the headroom of your process, but obviously there will still be a limit.

Comment: Is there any other way to quickly check in a dataframe. It is taking 50 sec to complete a 500 records

Comment: There is an .isin() method on the pd.Series object that should be able to help you. If the data is already in a DataFrame, you ought to use the methods available.